# Windows Authentication use groupsid claims instead on role claims in IsInRole function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, windows-authentication, claims-based-identity

I'm building MVC 5 webapp with Windows Authentication.
Since I have external authorization store, so I want to add some custom claims authentication. I handle the PostAuthenticationRequest event

```
void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
{
    if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var id = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First();
        ...
        //query authorization store
        id.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "SomeRole"));
    }
 }
```

Then in controller, I check the IsInRole("SomeRole") , but I found it always return false even the identity have the SomeRole role claim

Then I found out that in Windows Authentication, the IsInRole() is using groupsid claims as role

Instead of add my custom claim to groupsid claim, how can I set the IsInRole function use the standard Role claims?

Look like RoleClaimType is the way to go, but it is readonly I cannot set it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the behavior of the [`WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.isinrole(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

What you can do is create a new `ClaimsPrincipal` from a new `ClaimsIdentity`, using the claims from the `WindowsPrincipal`. One of the `ClaimsIdentity` [constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194499(v=vs.110).aspx) lets you specify the `nameType` and `roleType`.

Having set the new ClaimsPrincipal, your IsInRole calls should work on the specified roleType.